# How do you do a neck flip?

Tags: hill-climb-racing, hill-climb-racing-2

I've seen  *0 x Neck Flip*  but sometimes I wonder how to do one. Does anybody have any idea how to  do one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neck flip is performed during a "race ending crash" - basically you have to clip an object with your head/face and the resulting physics causes your avatar (racer) to "flip"

There is no specific "course" or "race mode" you need to be in (would probably be easiest in adventure mode, you could fine tune your approach). Literally all you need to do, is jump/launch into the air, and then before you land, you need to faceplant/smash *only* your head into some sort of obstacle so that the physics code in the game sends your racer "flipping"

Its just a ragdoll physics mechanism and there are endless opportunities to accomplish this in the game.

**One specific thing you will need** : you can only accomplish a neck flip when using a vehicle that your racer's head is exposed ( Dirtbike / Scooter / Tank / monowheel / etc.. )

Answer (score -1):

I think it's easiest to do one coming off a bridge (do a wheelie on the bridge, then when you hit the corner, it flings you forward and does a flip, but if you want a neck flip, use a car without a cover, like the motocross, and do the instructions.)